# JOOQ - nested query

Tags: java, sql, jooq

I'm trying to write this query with jooq

```
SELECT region.*, 
       (SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM city 
        WHERE city.region_id = region.id) AS num
FROM region;
```

I tried few things, but no success. So far I got nothing more than

```
dsl.select().from(Tables.REGION).fetch();
```

How can I add the `num` column to my result? Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your query will look something like this:

```
// This is how you can select REGION.*
dsl.select(REGION.fields())

// This is how you can add more fields to the SELECT clause
   .select(

// Nested selects are just select() as well (from DSL)
        select(count())
       .from(CITY)
       .where(CITY.REGION_ID.eq(REGION.ID))

// This is how you convert an org.jooq.Select into a Field
       .asField("num")
   )
   .from(REGION)
   .fetch();
```

The above implementation is assuming static imports:

```
import static org.jooq.impl.DSL.*;
import static path.to.generated.Tables.*;
```